# Same regex evaluated differently with sed than with grep

Tags: regex, bash, sed, grep

Consider following commands

```
~ echo "f(ew)" > t
~ egrep "f\([^\)]*\)" t
f(yo)
```

as expected `egrep` matches the whole line.

But for the following commands the regex doesn't catch the last parenthese

```
~ echo "f(ew)" > t
~ sed -i "s/f\([^\)]*\)/yo/" t
~ cat t
yo)
```

why isn't the last parenthese catched?

Comment: Are you sure about the output of the first case?

Comment: @MarounMaroun: thanks; I just added the `\\` that SO removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escaping a parenthesis (== normal round brace) within the pattern in sed is part of the special mechanism we use to name the matched string in the substitution string by using \1, \2, etc.

So in your case you don't want sed to interpret your parenthesis as these special characters, but just leave them depict the character they are :) So:

```
sed -i 's/f([^)]*)/yo/' t
```

This is the solution brought by konsolebox, but @konsolebox: this is not "quoting/unquoting" that we are talking about, but "escaping" (the characters '(' and ')').

Comment: this works. I'm surprised though; typically in a regex `\(` denotes the char and `(` denotes a catching parenthesis. In this case it seems to the other way around. Why's that?

Comment: In extended regexps the parenthesis has a special meaning, but NOT in non-extended regexps (those sed uses by default if you don't give it the -r flag). the "\\( ... \\)" mechanism of pattern memorization is a sed thing, not belonging to any set of regular expression metacharacters.

Answer (score 2):

Don't quote it:

```
sed -i "s/f([^)]*)/yo/" t
```

Or perhaps use `-E`/`-r`:

```
sed -E -i "s/f\([^)]*\)/yo/" t
sed -r -i "s/f\([^)]*\)/yo/" t
```

`-E` or `-r` makes it interpret the pattern like `egrep`:

> -r, --regexp-extended
>          use extended regular expressions in the script.

Comment: why does the not extended regex treat `(` as a char and `\(` as a catching parenthesis? Usually it's the other way around for regex patterns